# In Java, if a class implements an interface, do I need to compile the interface?

Tags: java, interface

My previous thinking was that I had to compile the interface along with the implementing class for the implementing class to understand static data belonging to the interface.

For instance if the interface has a data field, `public static final int six = 6`, if I wanted to use `six` in the compiled class and run a program using this class and uses `six`, I would have to include the compiled interface class also.

This does not seem like the case, how does the implementing class even know that it has this data field without the compiled interface?

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted to use `six` in the compiled class and run a program using this class and uses `six`, I would have to include the compiled interface class also.

## Correct.

**However**, a `static final` value will likely be inlined by the java compiler to the constant value (at *compile time*). You can examine the byte-code with something like

```
javap -v MyClass.class
```

Comment: What else is inlined? `final`, `static`? Or is it only when putting the two together `static final`?